# How to only write 'x' amount of a Byte object (raw .ogg sound file) to a file in Python

Tags: python, arrays, file, audio, ogg

I have a script to write musical notes to a directory based on the byte object returned from my HTTP request. The problem I am having is that the .ogg sound file is 5 seconds long and ideally I would like to shorten this to 0.5 seconds. Is this possible to do so by simply dropping chunks of the byte object?
I know via pysoundfile it is possible to use the frames and sample rate to calculate duration and therefore write 'x' frames. This is only possible for static rates however and the sample rate for these files are not known due to the musical notes being extracted in raw form.

Some of the code I have written is below.

```
        for notenumbers in range(48, 64+1):
            note = requests.get(url.format(instrument, notenumbers))
            notebinary = note.content
            time.sleep(3)
            with open("E:\\useraccount\\x\\x\\"+str(dirname)+"\\"+str(instrname)+"\\"+str(instrname) +"-" +str(notenumbers) +".ogg", "wb") as o:
                print("Creating file named: " +str(instrname) +":" +str(notenumbers) +".ogg")
                o.write(notebinary)
```

Thank you if you are able to help with this!

Comment: `bytes` objects can be sliced so you can write an arbitrary portion of `notebinary`. Are you asking how to determine the *time length* of a portion on `notebinary` when you don't have any information related to time in the dayta?

Comment: @wwii I essentially have a raw byte object with no metadata relating to sample rate, time length etc. As you correctly said I am looking to determine the duration of a slice of the byteobject without any relevant metadata that is commonly stored with the .ogg files.

Comment: In that case you should change your question or ask a new one.

Comment: @martineau I believe the question is still relevant. I  am trying to write a certain amount of a byte object based on that amount mapping to 'x' seconds.

Comment: .ogg file have a [documented file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg#File_format), so theoretically you could parse it and extract what you want. Asking for a software recommendation of a library or module you could use from Python is off-topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: @martineau I am new to stackoverflow and related sites so I apologise! I will check the link out. Thanks!